# Equations of the points

Tags: analytic-geometry

In an orthonormal system of coordinates we consider the points A(2, 0) and B(0, 1) and two “moving” points: P (x, 0) Q(0, −3x)
with x < 0.
Consider now the set of all points obtained by intersecting the straight lines PB and QA.
Find the equation of this set of points ?

Comment: Any thoughts? What did you try?

Comment: This is essentially the same as [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3604430/265466), just with different numbers. Once you can solve that problem you can handle this one, too. This isn’t a “do my homework for me” site, though. This question has the same issues as have been pointed out for that one. As they are, both questions stand a good chance of simply being closed. If you don’t want that to happen, edit them to include the information described in [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/265466) for ways to improve these questions.

Comment: Can I find the equation of the line of PB and QA and then set them equal to each other? Then  y intercept of PB is (0,1) and Your y intercept of QA is (0,-2x) then Find the slope of each line and set them equal thats what I would do but I’m not sure

Comment: Any help ? Because I’m not sure

Comment: Here's a visualization of the situation: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3h5aox8ovr

Comment: I would recommend forming the general equations of the two lines; and then solving for their intersection.